# Iterate over a generic Lookup

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I want to pass a generic `Lookup<type1, type2>` to an object. In this object I want to iterate over the generic lookup while accessing specific properties. How Can I do this?

A different approach would also be ok for me. I have `Enumerable<type>` which I have to group by any property (thats why I've choosen `Lookup`). In the target Object I have to iterate group-wise over this collection and then iterate over each group, picking specific properties of `type`.

```
class Record
{
    public DateTime RecordDate {get; set;}
    public string Info1 {get; set;}
    public string Info2 {get; set;}
}

class TargetObject<type1, type2>
{
    public Lookup<type1, type2> myLookup;
    public TargetObject(Lookup<type1, type2> lookup)
    {
        myLookup = lookup;
    }

    public void TestFunc()
    {
        foreach(var item in myLookup)
        {
            var x = item.Key;
            foreach(var subItem in item)
            {
                var y = subItem. //here i like to acces type2-specific properties like Record.Info2 in a generic way
            }
        }
    }
}

List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
Lookup<DateTime, Record> lookup = records.ToLookup(r => r.RecordDate);

var target = new TargetObject(lookup);
```

Comment: this line should be fixed `var x = item.key;`  key property is started from the capital letter, `Key`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks. just typed this example without an editor.

Comment: You can use constraints to specify that `type2` should implement an interface that exposes the properties you want.  Though at that point you might as well just specify that type instead of using generics. Or maybe passing in a delegate would make sense.  What exactly do you plan to do with the value?

Comment: @juharr i will check if constraints could work in this case. specifying the type doesn't work for me, because I have to use that class with a couple of different types

Answer (score 1):

> //here i like to acces type2-specific properties like Record.Info2 in a generic way

The problem is, if you're truly generic, you don't know what those properties are. For that matter, neither do we. What do you want to do this data? It seems like you won't know that answer up front.

But there's good news... that makes this the perfect use case for a delegate!

```
public void TestFunc(Action<type1, type2> doSomething)
{
    foreach(var item in myLookup)
    {
        var x = item.Key;
        foreach(var subItem in item)
        {
            doSomething(x, subItem);
        }
    }
}
```

And now you'd call it with a lambda, like this:

```
var target = new TargetObject(lookup);
target.TestFunc((x, y) => {
    // x is the key
    // y is the subitem
    // Whatever code you put here will run once for every subitem.
    // And you will be able to use properties and methods of y.
    // As a bonus, you also have access to variables in outer scope via closures.
});
```

Comment: thats an interesting approach. i will try it. at the first look this could work for me.